# Fluent NHibernate automapping class conventions aren't being applied to entire class hierarchy

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping, convention-over-configur, table-per-subclass

I'm trying to automap a simple inheritance hierarchy with Fluent Nhibernate, and I need to have a slightly different name for each table than its class (underscores instead of Pascal case).  This seems like an obvious place to use conventions.  I also want to use the table-per-subclass strategy, but the combination seems to be causing me an issue: the convention is only applied to the base class of the hierarchy.

Here's my automapping:

```
AutoMap
    .AssemblyOf<BaseRule>()
    .IncludeBase<BaseRule>() // "BaseRule" is an abstract class
    .Conventions.Add( DefaultCascade.All() )
    .Conventions.Add<OracleTableNameConvention>()
```

How I want my classes mapped (class name -> table name):

```
  abstract class BaseRule -> Base_Rule
  class NumberRule : BaseRule -> Number_Rule
  class PatternStringRule : BaseRule -> Pattern_String_Rule
```

What I'm actually getting:

```
  BaseRule -> Base_Rule
  NumberRule -> NumberRule
  PatternStringRule -> PatternStringRule
```

As you can see, only the base class is actually being changed. Here's my existing convention, just so you can see how I'm defining it:

```
public class OracleTableNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        string fixedName = instance.EntityType.Name.ToUnderscoredNaming();
        instance.Table(fixedName);
    }
}
```

I've also looked into the `ISubclassConvention` interface, and can see no way in there to adjust the name of the table (which makes enough sense, subclasses aren't always in their own table).

If I delete the `IncludeBase` line from my automapping, the names become what I want, except it becomes table-per-concrete-class.  I want to use table-per-*subclass*, leaving all the common data in one shared base table.

I can add overrides for each name, and I will if I have to, but I'd rather not.

It **seems** like this should be an obviously supported behavior. How can I have the naming convention apply to each table in the hierarchy, without going to table-per-concrete-class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as I posted this question, I figured it out.

`IJoinedSubclassConvention` is the interface I needed to implement.

```
public class OracleSubClassConvention : IJoinedSubclassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IJoinedSubclassInstance instance)
    {
        string fixedName = instance.EntityType.Name.ToUnderscoredNaming();
        instance.Table(fixedName);
    }
}
```

I found it by looking for anything that had a method `Table(string)`.